# how does a propagation delay is being considered as part of a nodal delay?

Tags: network, networking

considering the definition of nodal delay, it's the time taken by the network node devices(router, switch, and hub) to process a packet and forward it to the receiver.
so propagation delay is a delay of the packet in the transmission media before it makes it to the receiving end once it left the sending node.
how is that propagation delay is being considered as part of nodal delay?

Comment: "_how is that propagation delay is being considered as part of nodal delay?_" It is not. I am not sure why you think it may be.

Comment: I have read a book "Computer Networking A TopDown Approach 6th Edition" aside from different references like https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/JustinLiller/Nodal+Delay this one and other. that is why!